# Combining split parts causing brick-like texture issue

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So, I split up a modified sphere shape for a collision mesh, I then copied & combined it all for the actual model only to find that it made the sphere look like it was made of glass bricks. It was meant to be a fully smooth glass sphere.

[image: Split objects that were joined]
[image]

I'm hoping there is a way to fix this without needing to recreate the object as it took a while to align the collision mesh up in-game.

Comment: Your topology doesn't look right, the rings seem disconnected. Also by the looks of it you have flipped normals on some faces. Select all vertices and try SHIFT + N to recalculate the normals.

Comment: The normals are flipped because the sphere is supposed to be a room, the inside is where players be at. I did SHIFT + N and nothing changed unfortunately.

Everything seems to be perfectly connected as well, when clicking l in edit mode I notice the brick patterns are being highlighted, I just can't find a way to unlink it.

Comment: That's not what I meant, you have some faces that have distinctly darker shading then the ones next to them, which is usually an indicator for flipped normals (on that specific face).  You can also recalculate inside (SHIFT + CTRL + N). I suggest you re-create the mesh from a sphere, it's likely faster then fixing the broken topology.